# Migrated SSRS Report Server Shared Schedules 2008 R2 to 2016 - not Alphabetical

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

We migrated all reports from 2008 R2 to 2016 but when going to select Shared Schedules, they are in some type of order that is not alphabetical - is there a setting to change this somewhere to fix to alphabetical?

#### Shared Schedules Not Alphabetical

[image: Shared Schedules Not Alphabetical]

Comment: Please give an example how they are sorted. Please be aware that sorting depends on the configured language and culture. Take a look at the regional settings of your new server 2016.

Comment: Thanks! added image - we will look at the regional settings.